# How to uninstall hive 0.11.0 on amazon and install 0.9.0

Tags: hive, microstrategy

I am working on a POC with Microstrategy 9.3.1 and hive 0.11.0. Recently I learnt that Microstrategy does not support 0.11.0. I have Hive running on Amazon. Now, I need help to uninstall hive 0.11.0 in Amazon and install hive 0.9.0.
Pls help

Thanks

Bhuvana

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough just to unzip hive 0.9.0 in a folder and change `HIVE_HOME` to point to that folder and add `$HIVE_HOME/bin` to your `PATH`.

For more info you can check [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/GettingStarted#GettingStarted-InstallationandConfiguration), but it should be straight forward.

Anyway MicroStrategy 9.4, released few weeks ago, is certified also for Hive 0.11, so maybe you can just install this latest release.